# Switching colors individually in different <td>

Tags: javascript

I want to toggle the background color of different empty table cells. Found here a Javascript that works well when it comes to toggle the background color, but I can not get it to work for the way I want it.

The example has three table cells, but only the last one is changeing the color - equal which one is clicked.

Tried for five hours to fix it and gave up... Javascript is to complicated for me.

Thanks in advance for the help, this problem really drives me insane.

```html
<html>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.bmm-01 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-02 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-03 td {background-color:#000000 }
-->
</style>

<head>

<script>
var colors = ["000000", "ffffff", "yellow", "blue", "gray"]; var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() { var col = document.getElementById("bmm-01"); if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) { colorIndex = 0; }
col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]; colorIndex++; }

var colors = ["000000", "ffffff", "yellow", "blue", "gray"]; var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() { var col = document.getElementById("bmm-02"); if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) { colorIndex = 0; }
col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]; colorIndex++; }

var colors = ["000000", "ffffff", "yellow", "blue", "gray"]; var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() { var col = document.getElementById("bmm-03"); if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) { colorIndex = 0; }
col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]; colorIndex++; }
</script>

<title>Title</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#f5f5f5" text="#f8f8ff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scroll="no">

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" width="100%" height="100%">
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#2977cc" height="1" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><font size="6"><b>Title</b></font></td><tr>

<td align="right" valign="top" width="50%">

<table border="1" width="150">
<td id="bmm-01" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor();" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
<td id="bmm-02" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor();" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
<td id="bmm-03" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor();" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
</table>

</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">

Content

</td><tr><td align="center" height="1" bgcolor="#606060" colspan="2">

Footer

</td>

</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: [This is my attempt.](https://jsfiddle.net/601qo1t2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've defined the changeColor() function three times. Javascript only recognizes one function definition per function name, and so you've essentially overwritten the first two definitions with the last definition. Because of that, all three cells trigger the same exact function when clicked, and that function changes the last cell.

This **does not** mean that you need a separate function for each cell. When you click on a cell, the browser calls the function that you specify in the html, but you can also pass an argument to that function, which represents the element that was clicked, like so:

```
<a onclick="changeColor(this)"></a>
```

Right now, your changeColor function does not take a parameter so the definition doesn't know anything about which cell was clicked, but this is easily fixed - Just add the parameter:

```
function changeColor(cell) { 
    var col = document.getElementById("bmm-03"); 
    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) { 
        colorIndex = 0; 
    }
    col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]; 
    colorIndex++; 
}
```

Now you can access the cell that was clicked inside changeColor. Which means you no longer need to use `getElementById()`, you can just reference the clicked element directly. Knowing all that, you can redefine you function like so:

```
function changeColor(cell) { 
    if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) { 
        colorIndex = 0; 
    }
    cell.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex]; 
    colorIndex++; 
}
```

We're still not done yet though. You want each cell to cycle through its own set of colors - but you have the same problem with your color arrays that you did with your functions. They're all overwritten. But you **only need one** color array, then you can have an index associated with each cell. How to do this association? You can define a table which associates between elementIds and indices, like so:

```
var cellColors = {
    "bmm-01": 1,
    "bmm-02": 4,
    "bmm-03": 2
}
```

Another advantage of this, is that if you insert a new cell, with a new id, it can be automatically inserted into this table.

So, how does the final product look?

```js
var colors = ["#000000", "#ffffff", "yellow", "blue", "gray"];
var cellColors = {};

function changeColor(cell) {
    // We don't give this a value immediately, because we don't
    // yet know whether this cell has an entry in the cellColors table.
    var colorIndex;

    if (cellColors[cell.id] !== undefined) {
        colorIndex = cellColors[cell.id];
    } else {
        cellColors[cell.id] = 1;
        colorIndex = cellColors[cell.id];
    }

    cell.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];

    cellColors[cell.id]++;

    // Make sure the index stays within bounds
    cellColors[cell.id] = cellColors[cell.id] % colors.length;
}
```

```html
<html>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.bmm-01 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-02 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-03 td {background-color:#000000 }
-->
</style>

<head>

<title>Title</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#f5f5f5" text="#f8f8ff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scroll="no">

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" width="100%" height="100%">
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#2977cc" height="1" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><font size="6"><b>Title</b></font></td><tr>

<td align="right" valign="top" width="50%">

<table border="1" width="150">
<td id="bmm-01" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a id="bmm-a-01" onclick="changeColor(this)" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
<td id="bmm-02" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a id="bmm-a-02" onclick="changeColor(this)" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
<td id="bmm-03" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a id="bmm-a-03" onclick="changeColor(this)" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td><tr>
</table>

</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">

Content

</td><tr><td align="center" height="1" bgcolor="#606060" colspan="2">

Footer

</td>

</table>

</body></html>
```

I also changed your html so that your anchor elements have their own ids as well, which serve as the keys in the cellColors table. Hope you find all this helpful :)

Comment: Oh. My. God. Thank you very much for your help - it works now exactly the way I wanted it and the whole code is short. I could never have archieved this.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work as you expect because you are redefining the `changeColor` function (and colors array) 3 times, so the last function declaration will overwrite the first ones: this is why your code only works well for the last cell (the one whose id is `bmm-03`).
Supposing that you want a similar behavior for all the cells (a click on a cell will toggle the cell background color) you could simply pass the cell id to the `changeColor` function like this:

```html
<html>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {font-family: Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
.bmm-01 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-02 td {background-color:#000000 }
.bmm-03 td {background-color:#000000 }
-->
</style>

<head>

<script>

var colors = ["#000000", "#ffffff", "yellow", "blue", "gray"];
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor(cellId) {
   var col = document.getElementById(cellId);
   if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
      colorIndex = 0;
   }
   col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
   colorIndex++;
}

</script>

<title>Title</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#f5f5f5" text="#f8f8ff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scroll="no">

  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" width="100%" height="100%">
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#2977cc" height="1" colspan="2" rowspan="1">
  <font size="6"><b>Title</b></font>
</td>
<tr>

  <td align="right" valign="top" width="50%">

    <table border="1" width="150">
      <td id="bmm-01" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor('bmm-01');" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td>
      <tr>
        <td id="bmm-02" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor('bmm-02');" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td>
        <tr>
          <td id="bmm-03" bgcolor="#000000" height="25"><a onclick="changeColor('bmm-03');" style="display:block; width: 100%">&nbsp;</a></td>
          <tr>
    </table>

  </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" width="50%">

    Content

  </td>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="1" bgcolor="#606060" colspan="2">

      Footer

    </td>

  </table>

</body>
</html
```

Be also aware that this code has some invalid property for  (`leftmargin`, `topmargin`,...) tag and also you were omitting the hash in front of colors code: `#000000` and `#ffffff`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort - I never expected two solutions in this short time. You guys are really the best! Case closed! 8)

Comment: This is a good solution too, but I'd just like to point out that it does not have each cell cycle through its own set of colors, since it only keeps one color index. So if you click the first cell when it's black, it turns white, but then if you click the second cell while it's black, it turns yellow. If this is your desired functionality then that's fine, but I just wanted to point out that the two solutions don't share the same behavior